# Efficiently using map function to render many React components

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, ecmascript-6

**Update**

The issue I'm facing is not with the components rerendering. I am already dealing with that by using shouldComponentUpdate and checking the ID of the updated component versus the ID of the current component. My questions specifically has to do with the initial load of the table and steps.

---

**Final Update**

The issue was caused by CKEditor 5 being rendered inside of every step

---

I am writing a React application that is responsible for rendering many tables with many steps inside them with many nested conditionals tables (If, then). The data for these tables are inside a JSON file that I am storing in Redux. I began rendering all of the tables (6) with a map function and that worked great; however, inside each of the Table components I have a function that maps over the steps (6-28 per table). When I did this, React started to take about 13 seconds to render the components to the screen.

I have used shouldComponentUpdate to make sure that the Table and Table Steps are not unnecessarily rendering more than once but it is still very slow. In the Table component, I am calling a function that maps over the JSON to render each of the Step components inside my render method.

The data variable in map contains the entire JSON structure for the current step, this includes text and nested conditionals

Table.js

```
  renderSteps = () => {
      const steps = this.props.currentDocument.data.items[0].tables[0][this.props.initialTableName].steps.map((data, index) =>
        <Step
          key={data.id}
          tableName={this.props.initialTableName}
          tableID={this.props.tableID}
          stepIndex={index}
          stepID={data.id}
          data={data}
        />
      );
      return steps;
    }
  };

render() {
  return (
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <th>Step</th>
              <th>Action</th>
            </tr>
            {this.renderSteps()}
          </tbody>
        </table>
  )
}
```

The parent component that renders the Table.js Component is setup in the same way.

Is there a way to make this initial load faster? I know that there are a lot of steps that contain a lot of data but I'm sure there is something I am missing to improve render performance.

I expect the page to load quicker than 10 - 15 seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Really great article about performance optimization - [Article about performance](https://www.codementor.io/blog/react-optimization-5wiwjnf9hj)

I hope it will be useful for you.

You could use `react-virtualized` to Memoize your big data/tables/scrolls.

- `React.memo` - to do the same with whole component
- `reselect` - the same with props.